an interesting coincidence with group orders: is there some theorem explaining it?
The sequence  OEIS A333646: $1,6,15,28,30,33,40,42,51,66,69,84,91,95,102,105,117,120,135,138,140,141,145,159,165,182,186,190,210,213,\cdots$
Contains numbers that are divisible by the largest prime factor of the sum of their own divisors. For instance the sum of divisors of $15$ is $24$, the biggest prime divisor of $24$ is $3$, and $3$ divides $15$.

If $G$ is a group and $|G|>6$ is featured in the sequence above, it seems guaranteed there will be at least one element of $G$ that has an order which is not a power of a prime. I've verified this up to and including $213$, and the pattern feels pretty compelling. I wonder, is there some theorem explaining this?

The converse does not hold, with the smallest example being $|G|=45$. But in general, at least for small numbers, a group with elements of exclusively power-of-prime orders can be constructed more often than not. For instance if $|G|=20$ we have $G=F_5$.
EDIT: @diracdeltafunk was kind enough to verify this up to order 1065, and @testacount has a promising lead for a full explanation. Hopefully I'll have more time to pursue it later this week.

EDIT: When thinking of groups $G$ such that the order of every element must be a power of a prime, two families are immediate examples:

$p$-groups (ie. groups whose orders are powers of primes)
non-abelian groups of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes and $p$ divides $q+1$.

And, apart from $1$ and $6$, groups from neither family may have orders in A333646.
But there are also (comparatively sparse) additional cases, such as $12,18,20,24,36,44,\cdots$ this explanation doesn't account for.

Not every cyclic group in a $p$ group is simple. Not sure what "$F_5$" means, or why it has order $20$.

@ArturoMagidin : Re: simple groups, an embarrasing mistake on my end. What I'm interested in is groups where every element has an order that is the power of some prime. Re: $F_5$, I'm going by the terminology provided by https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/. So $F_5$ is the $5$th Frobenius group, or $C_5⋊C_4$

Verified up to order 455, which is as high as OEIS lists this sequence.

@diracdeltafunk -- wow, nice job, thanks!

There is a classification of finite groups where every element has prime power order, and there are not too many possibilities. List out the orders of these groups and it becomes a number-theoretical question. For the classification see for example Section 2 of Lewis, M.L. Groups Having all Elements off a Normal Subgroup with Prime Power Order. Vietnam J. Math. 51, 577–587 (2023). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10013-022-00591-2

This probably closes the case with a little thought :) I've verified the conjecture up to order 1065, and I'll stop there.

@testaccount Sure the orders are already enough ? We want to show that every group with an order in the above mentioned sequence has the desried property. Also, can this classification be described shortly ?
